# Get the global transform matrix of an svg element

Tags: javascript, svg

I'd like to use browser svg+JavaScript to generate dynamic images from user-prepared svg templates (say, created in Inkscape) where there are rectangular placeholders that mark the place where the dynamic graphics should be placed.

Ideally, users - the template creators - should be allowed to move, scale, rotate, skew the rectangles (not so much rectangles after skewing) any way they want. The only thing they must do is to set the correct id value for those placeholder rectangles.

I am looking for a way how to get/calculate the transform matrix of those placeholders. Since they can be nested in groups, it is not enough to read the element's properties.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The SVG commands `getCTM` and/or `getScreenCTM` may be what you're looking for. (CTM stands for 'Current Transform Matrix', I believe.) You can use them, for example, by retrieving an element with jQuery, stripping away the enclosing jQuery object and invoking the command, e.g. `$("#mySvgCircleId")[0].getScreenCTM()`. They both return SVG matrix objects. Both will give you matrix information that takes into account their own direct transformations as well as any transformations that have been applied to any parental svg elements that the shapes are nested within. That sounds like what you were looking for.

Note, though, that there are important differences between the two commands. I demonstrate some of those differences in the code snippet below. There I show two `svg` elements, one with two red rectangles and one with two blue ones. All rectangles have the same width and height, but one of each colour is untransformed while the other is nested within three differently transformed groups. The output shows the matrix results using `getCTM` and `getScreenCTM` for each rectangle. Note the following:

- Both `getCTM` and `getScreenCTM` take into account transforms of any enclosing ancestor elements, e.g. any `g` group elements, up to the enclosing `svg` element. e.g. The returned matrices are different for 'untransformedRect1' and 'transformedRect1' for both commands.
- The `getCTM` results are not affected by the location of the enclosing `svg` element in its parental element, while the `getScreenCTM` results are. e.g. The results for 'untransformedRect1' and 'untransformedRect2' are identical when using `getCTM` but are different when using `getScreenCTM`.

There may be further complications if, for example, you're dealing with iframes, nesting svg elements within other svg elements, etc., which I'm not addressing here.

```js
var infoType = "CTM";
show("Matrix Results from getCTM()");
show(getInfo(infoType, "untransformedRect1"));
show(getInfo(infoType, "transformedRect1"));
show(getInfo(infoType, "untransformedRect2"));
show(getInfo(infoType, "transformedRect2"));
show("<br />");

var infoType = "ScreenCTM";
show("Matrix Results from getScreenCTM()");
show(getInfo(infoType, "untransformedRect1"));
show(getInfo(infoType, "transformedRect1"));
show(getInfo(infoType, "untransformedRect2"));
show(getInfo(infoType, "transformedRect2"));

function getInfo(mtrx, id) {
  var mtrx;
  if (infoType === "CTM") {
    var mtrx = $("#" + id)[0].getCTM();
  } else if (infoType === "ScreenCTM") {
    var mtrx = $("#" + id)[0].getScreenCTM();
  }
  var str =
    r(mtrx.a) + ",  " +
    r(mtrx.b) + ",  " +
    r(mtrx.c) + ",  " +
    r(mtrx.d) + ",  " +
    r(mtrx.e) + ",  " +
    r(mtrx.f);
  return id + ": matrix: " + str;
}

function r(num) {
  return Math.round(num * 1000) / 1000;
}

function show(msg) {
  document.write(msg + "<br />");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Depending on how you are viewing this, you may need to scroll down to see the matrix values.</p>
<div id="containerForSvgs">
  <svg id="svg1" width="150" height="100">
    <rect id="background1" width="300" height="200" fill="#eee" transform="translate(0,0)"></rect>
    <rect id="untransformedRect1" width="20" height="10" fill="red"></rect>
    <g id="group1A" transform="scale(2)">
      <g id="group1B" transform="translate(40,20)">
        <g id="group1C" transform="rotate(-15)">
          <rect id="transformedRect1" width="20" height="10" fill="red"></rect>
        </g>
      </g>
    </g>
  </svg>
  <br />
  shift ===>
  <svg id="svg2" width="150" height="100">
    <rect id="background2" width="300" height="200" fill="#eee" transform="translate(0,0)"></rect>
    <rect id="untransformedRect2" width="20" height="10" fill="blue"></rect>
    <g id="group2A" transform="scale(2)">
      <g id="group2B" transform="translate(40,20)">
        <g id="group2C" transform="rotate(-15)">
          <rect id="transformedRect2" width="20" height="10" fill="blue"></rect>
        </g>
      </g>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
<br />
```

**UPDATE** Actually, while investigating this I dug a little deeper into the SVG specifications and discovered a very cool other function that might be even more powerful for what you want: `getTransformToElement`. Basically you can retrieve the cumulative transformation matrix from any element (which I'll call `target`) to any of its enclosing elements (which I'll call `enclosing`) in a single command: `target.getTransformToElement(enclosing)`.

I've provided another code snippet below that demonstrates its behaviour, with id's named that will hopefully make it clear how it could be relevant to your situation. The snippet shows that `target.getCTM()` essentially provides the same output as `target.getTransformToElement(enclosingSvgElement)`. In addition, however, it also shows that it is more flexible by being able to show the transform from a sub-sub-nested element to any of its ancestral enclosing elements, up any arbitrary distance. Moreover, you can look in either direction, e.g. both `target.getTransformToElement(enclosing)` and `enclosing.getTransformToElement(target)`, where one will be the matrix inverse of the other (if I'm getting my mathematical terminology correct here).

```js
var svg  = $("svg"                                            )[0];
var grp1 = $("#grp1_formatting_of_entire_app"                 )[0];
var grp2 = $("#grp2_menus_and_buttons_and_stuff"              )[0];
var grp3 = $("#grp3_main_drawing_canvas"                      )[0];
var grp4 = $("#grp4_some_intervening_group"                   )[0];
var shp1 = $("#shp1_the_shape_I_currently_care_about"         )[0];
var grp5 = $("#grp5_a_lower_group_I_dont_currently_care_about")[0];

var shp1_CTM     = shp1.getCTM();
var shp1_to_svg  = shp1.getTransformToElement(svg);
var shp1_to_grp3 = shp1.getTransformToElement(grp3);
var grp3_to_shp1 = grp3.getTransformToElement(shp1);

document.write("<table>");

show("getCTM for shp1"                                 , shp1_CTM    );
show("getTransformToElement from shp1 to enclosing svg", shp1_to_svg );
show("getTransformToElement from shp1 to grp3"         , shp1_to_grp3);
show("getTransformToElement from grp3 to shp1"         , grp3_to_shp1);

document.write("</table>");


function show(msg, mtrx) {
  document.write("<tr><td>" + msg + "</td><td>" + mtrxStr(mtrx) + "</td></tr>");
}

function mtrxStr(mtrx) {
  return "( " +
    rnd(mtrx.a) + ", " +
    rnd(mtrx.b) + ", " +
    rnd(mtrx.c) + ", " +
    rnd(mtrx.d) + ", " +
    rnd(mtrx.e) + ", " +
    rnd(mtrx.f) + " )";
}

function rnd(n) {
  return Math.round(n*10)/10;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg width="200" height="60">
  <g            id="grp1_formatting_of_entire_app"                  transform="translate(30.0, 0)">
    <g          id="grp2_menus_and_buttons_and_stuff"               transform="translate(10.0, 0)">
      <g        id="grp3_main_drawing_canvas"                       transform="translate( 3.0, 0)">
        <g      id="grp4_some_intervening_group"                    transform="translate( 1.0, 0)">
          <rect id="shp1_the_shape_I_currently_care_about"          transform="translate( 0.3, 0)"
                 x="0" y="0" width="100" height="40" fill="red"></rect>
          <g    id="grp5_a_lower_group_I_dont_currently_care_about" transform="translate( 0.1, 0)">
          </g>
        </g>
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
<p>Results</p>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, Chrome does not support this cool function anymore: https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5736166087196672

Comment: That's seriously too bad, 'cause I was quite excited about finding this. It would make manipulations in a heavily grouped svg image much easier. Oh well. Thanks very much for the info.

Comment: You can use a polyfill for browsers that don't support that function (stupid chrome...)        SVGElement.prototype.getTransformToElement = SVGElement.prototype.getTransformToElement || function(toElement) {
    return toElement.getScreenCTM().inverse().multiply(this.getScreenCTM());
  };

Comment: @JasonCrist, that's a great polyfill, thanks! I worry, though. Polyfills often exist for features that have yet to be implemented by a particular browser. Here it's for a feature that had already been implemented and then was actively removed. Does that represent back-room conversations that are part of a broader trend to remove this feature from all browsers? If so, then at some point such polyfills might be uphill battles that aren't worth fighting. However, if at least `getScreenCTM` is here to stay then your solution is still definitely valuable.